# Air Conditioner Compressor Inoperative

Tags: repair, air-conditioning

My home air conditioning / heat only blows ambient temperature air through the vents, there is no temperature change through the unit.  Inspecting it, the condensor fan is spinning, as is the evaporator fan (since I feel the air from the vents).  I'm hearing a strange noise from what I assume is the compressor, and the lights in my house dim when the noise is occurring.

Here is a video of it happening: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZQc6V8ojNN4qEFAW2 .  The lights dim when the "hum" occurs.

I don't have the tools to check the refrigerant pressures, but I am comfortable with electrical.  Is it worth trying to inspect the capacitor, or do I likely have other issues?

I have a Goodman Packaged Unit/RTU Model PHKJ042-1.  No breakers are tripped, cycling them has no effect.

Comment: Turn it off, now. You could try a new cap; that's like a $10 try. Compressor's prob shot, which means buying a whole new condenser. I've never know anyone to replace a compressor inside of a condenser. Verify you've got 220 at the condenser.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the household lights dim when the humming occurs.

Comment: Try the cap first, but that is usually for the condensor fan and not the compressor. Now, weight the costs of repair vs replace. Don't just jump to replace if the compressor is fairly new, uses a lower cost refrigerant and can be swapped easily. An HVAC tech will need to do this because of the refrigerant. The compressor will make some noise as it is compressing the refrigerant, however, dimming the lights means an excessive draw of power.

Comment: It could also be fine, and you may have a leak in the refrigerant lines, therefore the compressor is not working properly. Best to get it checked by a tech and go from there. I had someone tell me I needed to replace my condensing unit because it groaned and didn't cool the home. Turned out to be a leak discovered by myself while it was running. I heard a hissing and the filter had a leak in one end. I replaced the filter, called a different company out. He vacuumed the system, held vac and so he charged it up. A year later it still works like new. The first company looked at how old the unit

Comment: was and said replace, without really looking at it. He didn't even turn it on or get his equipment out. So I told him bye bye and I wouldn't pay his service call fee. He sat in his truck, called his boss, came back and said, we will replace it for $4000, I said, nope again, then he left.

Comment: there may be a start capacitor and a start relay .... i had a start relay fail on a fridge. the relay was not mechanical, but it was a disk about the size of a CR2032 battery ... you may have something similar

Comment: Start checking your 220V the dimming of the lights and the hum sound - could be the compressor capacitors are bad (Start cap. ).  Also check to make sure you have 220V at the condenser terminals AND compressor - some breakers were dual pole on L1 and L2 and one pole might be defective. Verify power at the terminal connection of the condenser. Then check at the compressor itself when the compressor is supposed to be running.

Comment: @jsotola HVAC condensers have typically have both a Start and Run capacitor. Generally they are run on separate winding's of the motor - for example a start winding might be its own winding.

Comment: @JeffCates Low refrigerant - In HVAC unit there is a cut off for low refrigerant - the Compressor will not run. Even if it did run with out refrigerant (yes it will burn up eventually ) that will not cause his lights to dim and a hum sound or the buzz sound. The hum sound comes from what sounds like his fan and the buzz sound his compressor is locked up (rotor lock on the motor).

Comment: I would suspect there is not always a cut off for low refrigerant, like I said, mine had a leak, and had been empty for almost a year. Started not cooling mid summer, I decided the following spring to check it out. No refrigerant in the system, but the compressor would still work. And mine had a single start/run capacitor. That was suspect initially before calling a tech out. So to say they won't work without refrigerant is not correct. It may be that some systems do have this protection built in, but I would assume it would not run the fan as well, signalling some type of error.

Comment: My particular system was a top of the line Carrier unit back 15 years ago, so things may have changed since. However, I would suspect the compressor, but without someone telling him how to check the motor or the relays, then its just guess work at this time. Could be any number of things. If his condensing fan is spinning, then the start/run cap is working. This then would lead to a relay that is chattering, won't close or compressor not working (burned out.)

Comment: My unit has a sensor called "Loss of Charge Protection" which I will assume is a low pressure switch.  Given the compressor buzzing, I'm guessing I have refrigerant

Comment: @JeffCates watch his video you will notice the condenser fan is spinning slowly so one of two things is happening a bad cap or no voltage on one of the power lines, also compressor not working (meaning there is probably a common denominator). The first thing to check is power prior to the Contactor before AC cool is called for, and after the Contactor when AC cool is called for (contactor on by system - not manual). Diagram shows T2 common between Condenser / Compressor and Capacitor Start/Run; check for bad CB supplying L1, L2, Bad contactor, or Bad capacitor (if not those compressor bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting that you do not have the correct power and possibly a capacitor is out as well.

I am going to state a couple observation about your video so read closely.

I am looking at your video post and watching the SLOW moving Condenser Fan and I also heard the BUZZ.

As for the condenser fan it seems like your RUN circuit is not powered up - this can be one of a couple things depending on how that motor is wired - and if it is 220V. Run Capacitor could be bad. However I suspect that you have a BAD phase feeding the AC unit.  The reason being is that your compressor is not running either.

Please Check your power coming off of your Circuit Breakers - check it at the Terminals of the Condenser Unit . You should have L1 and L2, check L1 - N(115V), L2 -N(115V), L1-G (115V), L2-G (115V) , L1- L2 (230V). I am suspecting a Circuit Breaker has high resistance and either not supplying power or supplying very little power - when measuring at the condenser watch which line (L1 or L2) DROPS when you start the unit up. That will tell you which side of the breaker is bad or possibly your contactor, You will need to measure on both sides of your contactor while doing this check (contactor only pulls in when compressor is told to run) Contactor T1 and Neutral , T2 and Neutral - you will need to verify both sides to know whether you have a bad contactor or a bad circuit breaker.

If you can post a picture of the wiring diagram found inside the panel cover that will help tremendously. Then I will know how that motor is configured for start winding or not.

When checking your capacitor (always be careful to discharge them before handling as you can get electrocuted [aka Killed] or shocked. To discharge them using a screw driver between Common and Herm or Fan (only handling the insulated part of the screw driver).

If your meter does not check Farads you can test the capacitor in the unit while the unit is "running" - well in your case on.

Measure the current (amps) of the motor start winding coming off of the capacitor (herm lead and also for the Fan lead) and multiply it times 2652 [in USA 60Hz numbers] then divide that number by the voltage you measure across the capacitor. This will tell the Farads of the capacitor and it should match the capacitor or be with in say 5% , sometimes 10% could be ok depending on the quality of the capacitor.

With the measurements you made; if you were to assume your capacitor was working you would find what current you should expect across those winding's Herm (yellow according to your diagram) and Fan (Brown according to your diagram).

From your Measurements on the Fan, I used a pseudo value of 1 amp on the winding  using that number your Fan capacitor is at 106 UF but the 5 UF capacitor is a typical proper sizing for a Fan motor. (1 AMP * 2652 ) / 25VAC = 106 UF you can see the amperage I have used is about 21 times too high so 1/21 = .0476 - I am sure that is too low of a current draw to start that motor - so I suspect Capacitor is bad.

Using the same Formula on the HERM (Compressor Side) your measurement was 240V 
So just assuming a low Amperage of 1 AMP (1 AMP * 2652 ) / 240VAC = 11.5 UF your capacitor is supposed to be 50UF or about 4.7 times greater than what our pseudo value gives us. So if you measured with an Amp Meter that the compressor was drawing roughly 4.5 ~ 5.0 Amps on that winding (yellow wire going from Capacitor to compressor) the capacitor for that side would be working.

Given the capacitor is bulging I suspect at least the capacitor has failed especially given your measurements - I know the fan side can't be working if that was truly the fan side you measured.

Now a suspicion I have about the readings you gave me .. If perhaps you mixed them up and got them backwards.. ~25V was on the HERM side and 240V was on the fan side the fan side would be working and the compressor side would not be working. Bad Capacitor.

50UF should be your compressor side and 5UF should be the AC Fan side. Your part number if my search was correct should be this: PPS550440RD ; However a capacitor that is a Dual 50UF & 5UF rated for 440 VAC will work fine. While your capacitor in the image is 370V , the higher voltage 440VAC has a little more headroom and your situation requires it .. 370V is typical in a 220V circuit here is the formula  1.56 * 220V = 343 VAC, However you have measured 240V which 1.56 * 240 V = 374 VAC and that is OVER the rating of your capacitor and therefore it probably went BULGE no worky after a while. So get one rated at 440CVAC or even 470 VAC.

Comment: The diagram is very weathered, but here's the same model from the S/M https://photos.app.goo.gl/kewfwRYXByOu2h9I3 .  I didn't realize the condensor fan was slow, and I will check the contactors tomorrow.  Thank you

Comment: I will also mention my unit does not have the start assist component (resistor?) next to the dual cap (Cap.1)

Comment: @Jeff I would check L2 & Neutral on the incoming side of the contactor ,AC Thermostat  AC is OFF but Circuit Breaker's ON.  Then I would check T2 opposite side of Contactor AC On and Calling for Cooling. According to the diagram it looks like there is a Red Wire that goes from T2 to Center Tap of Capacitor and also to the Compressor, I suspect low or no voltage at T2. The cap could be bad but check this first as it is in common with both and not usual that the cap blew both sides (it could but not usual). You can also unplug center tap check voltage on T2 if good now capacitor probly shorted.

Comment: Confirmed the contactor is fine, I didn't realize they'd have an open air casing.  But verified it closes and passes 240v on both sides.  With compressor activated, there is 240v on the common side of the cap, 240v on the "herm" compressor side, and only ~25v on the fan side.  I hsould note when doing this test the condensor fan no longer spun as well.  I've also measured 240v at the condensor fan when commanded on between common and the purple wire.

Comment: I've removed the capacitor and I don't think the casing is supposed to be this swollen.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/XmcnGMwNFfN2jceZ2 .  I'm going to go out and get a cap to install.

Comment: @Jeff  The contactor to check for voltage you allowed the Thermistat to call for cool and close it (right). I know you can push manually on them - but normal operation you don't do that and you always want to check a system how it normally would function. With the center tap wire removed measuring voltage should be 240V - means T2 is good. I am going to post some more information in my answer. Be careful with the capacitor - they store voltage and can kill or shock you.

Comment: @Jeff I posted mor einformation - make sure the capacitor you purchase is rated for at least 440VAC to 470VAC . 50UF & 5UF.

Comment: The start run cap needs to be replaced with one of a similar value.  The voltage rating can be anything above 390 v. Lights dimming and compressor not starting this is my first check, if a leg was out there would be no current draw and the lights wouldn't dim. If the value of the start run cap is not close to the original value in microfarids (uf) it is harder on the motor and may cause lights to flicker more on start up.

Comment: I was testing the contactor while commanding cooling on, I did not push on it.  The voltage readings were correct, as the fan had stopped working as I stated.

But the capacitor fixed it!  Thank you for your help, I learned a lot about this system.  I finally see where my auxiliary heating is (it wasn't working last winter), and I was able to wire in a common wire for the thermostat.  The Nest thermostat was current sapping to charge but now has a common feed.

You guys have been amazingly helpful, thank you!

Comment: I do think the low rating of the capacitor was the cause of the failure, as the previous technician (before I owned it) did a piss poor job.  I had to buy 40 screws that were missing from the casing, most panels were held on with 1 or 2 screws.  Given my entire unit including blower is located outside (South Carolina), this was the cause of many musty/moldy smells.

Comment: @Jeff I hate to say this but finding people that will actually do the job as if they would die if they did it wrong are few and hard to come by. I did not say as if they were doing their own - because some people don't even care about their own stuff.  Glad to hear you got your system working.